# jQuery offset top navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got code for smooth scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".nav").offset().top > 150) {
        $(".nav-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".nav-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});


$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

but after scrolling titles of section are hidden
I need to move it sth about 100px top? i tried:

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-100
```

or

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset({top: -100}).top
```

but this not work correctly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 100 to the top offset because its 0

```
nav-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Try this:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(".nav").offset().top + 100
}, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
```

You can check the values your variables with

```
console.log($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top);
```

happy coding!